# Performance when using document() repeatedly in xslt

Tags: xslt

Is it acceptable to call the same document throughout an xslt-file like this :

```
<xsl:value-of select="document('doc.xml')/root/bar/foo1" />
<xsl:value-of select="document('doc.xml')/root/bar/foo2" />
<xsl:value-of select="document('doc.xml')/root/bar/foo3" />
```

...?

I can imagine that caching avoids producing overhead for reading the file time after time.

Or should I store the doc.xm in a variable and  use that variable to query?

In this case I will have to use some sort of library like xsle since I am using xslt1.

Or is there any other solution?

Note : Some parts of the XPath should be dynamic like :

```
<xsl:value-of select="document('doc.xml')/root/*[name()=$lang]/foo3" />
```

Comment: To feel no doubts you can always *measure* the performance -- in this specific case the measurements should confirm Michael Kay's answer. In general, performance measurement is the recommended method to answer any such questions rather than believing anyone.

Comment: Dimitre, ofcoure, see my remark on Woody's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT processors are required to ensure that if you call document() twice with the same URL, the nodes returned are identical in the sense that count(document('a.xml')|document('a'xml')) = 1. It's quite hard to meet this requirement without caching the document, so I think you can be reasonably sure that each document will only be fetched and parsed once. However, putting it in a global variable will never do any harm.

Comment: If you are reasonably sure, so am I now :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Personally when I have used it I have always put it in a variable for convenience, or got the values I needed, just to make it easier to read. With MSXSL that I was last using I could put it in a node tree and access it that way.

I can't imagine that the XSL processor doesn't cache the same file in some way, but I suspect it is different for all processors and it doesn't seem to be written down.

If I wanted to know with the processor I was using, I would just copy and past for a big document and time it as a test, it doesn't take long to do and it is the only way to be sure on your system.

Comment: True enough, often there's no alternative for testing... But the same xslt-file however might be hosted on different platforms so a guideline or known 'by design behaviour" is welcome too.

Comment: Agreed. Well, using MSXSL4, I never noticed a performance differnce in either way, so I can only assume that there was caching (I was using big files). There is no requirement for it in the spec, but it would be hard to imagine it not being done